# jPlayer plays in mobile chrome not mp3

Tags: android, jquery, browser, jplayer

please, could you help me? 
I´m using jplayer. On desktop all browsers are ok, on iOs also but on Android it doesn´t play. I´m using mp3 format. If I include oga format, it plays song in oga format. Is there any way how to make jplayer being able to play mp3 format on Android mobile?

Thank you very much for your solutions.

Here is my source:

```
<div class="media-player">
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            $("#jquery_jplayer_foot_mob_1").jPlayer({
                                                ready: function() {
                                                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                                                        title: "4D - Zelený dym",
                                                        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg",
                                                        mp3: "files/audio/4D---Zeleny-dym-(2012).mp3"
                                                    });
                                                },
                                                play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
                                                    $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
                                                },
                                                errorAlerts: true,
                                                supplied: "oga, mp3",
                                                swfPath: "scripts/jplayer",
                                                solution: "html",
                                                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_foot_mob_1"
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <div id="jquery_jplayer_foot_mob_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                                    <div id="jp_container_foot_mob_1" class="jp-audio small cover">
                                        <div class="jp-type-single">
                                            <div class="jp-cover">
                                                <img src="styles/img/disc_1.png" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                                                <ul class="jp-controls">
                                                    <li class="left"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                                                    <li class="right"><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="jp-progress">
                                                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="jp-details">
                                                    <span class="jp-title"></span>
                                                    <div class="jp-time-holder">
                                                        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="jp-no-solution">
                                                <span>Update Required</span>
                                                To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                                            </div>
                                        </div></div>
```

Comment: No one know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change the code to assign a m4a instead of a mp3, but still keep the link to the mp3. That worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_foot_mob_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "4D - Zelený dym"
                m4a: "files/audio/4D---Zeleny-dym-(2012).mp3"
            });
        },
        play: function() { // To avoid multiple jPlayers playing together.
            $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        },
        errorAlerts: true,
        supplied: "m4a",
        swfPath: "scripts/jplayer",
        solution: "html",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_foot_mob_1"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Its just a bug of jPlayer)

In version 2.7.1 fixed this problem

https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/releases/tag/2.7.1